# What can I safely charge with the apple 20W power plug?

Tags: battery, power, charger

I once plugged a macbook air usb-c charger on a wireless speaker and it completely screwed the battery, so apparently, I can't charge any battery with any charger.

I just got a 20W apple charger for my iPhone 12. Can I safely charge my magic mouse with it? Amazon Kindle?

Comment: Suggest you label your chargers with what they are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can charge any standards-compliant device that uses USB-C for charging/powering.

Your experience with the wireless speaker demonstrates that the speaker itself was defective and/or not standards compliant - or that your particular charger was defective (which is not that likely given that you can charge your laptop with it).

Comment: I use my Apple Type C Charger for all type C products in my laptop bag. All devices have been working well since I started using it.